# Is there any way to convert ..PNG image to .DWG file & how to get manifest file along with converted .DWG for drawing_package in azure maps indoor?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-maps

**Prerequisites**

***To create indoor maps:***

=>Make an Azure Maps account
=>Obtain a primary subscription key, also known as the primary key or the subscription key.
=>Create a Creator resource
=>Download the *Sample Drawing package.*(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps)

**Requirement:** 1). I have sample .PNG image. I wanna convert this to .DWG and After conversion , I should be able to edit data in .DWG Is it possible ??

2). As you see above azure maps team provided some sample **"Sample Drawing Package"** for indoor map. This package you can download from the above link. If you download and open, there you can see 3 .dwg files (Basement.dwg,Ground.dwg, Level_2.dwg) along with **manifest.json** file.
So, How can I generate my own **manifest.json** file relates to converted
(.PNG to .DWG) file?

**NOTE:**
I have used https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/png_to_dwg.html and https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/download-draftsight/?wockw=Draftsight for converting .png to .dwg

Sample png file : [Floor03 Vertical.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ttof.png),
After conversion dwg file : [ConvertedFile.dwg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbqWY.png)

So, I request anyone suggest how can I get my own (conversion .png to .dwg) drawing_package along with manifest.json data ?

Comment: a PNG is a bitmap.  A DWG is a 2d/3d CAD file.  You may be able to convert them but the resulting DWG is probably not going to have the data needed by a mapping tool

Comment: Cross Referencing same question asked in Microsoft Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/55404/index.html

Comment: @Jason , Yes I have checked that I can convert  .PNG to .DWG . but, no proper data available for mapping tool. So, Do you have any idea how to create our own Sample_Drawing_Packages for indoor maps?

Comment: I imagine that you should use a CAD tool that produces DWG files.  Or hire a draftsman.

Comment: I used CAD tool "DraftSight" , but I am not getting that how to get JSON data from DWG file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to manually define your own manifest.json file. CAD tools are what architects use to design buildings. Another way to create a map is to use MS Graph. A script would have to be written to output the manifest.json, so that is something you would have to write.

If you would like to make a feature request please do it in https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps and share here so others can vote.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest.json is used to describe the DWG file for conversion to an indoor map. This file isn't automatically generated. Please see [Drawing Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/drawing-requirements) for additional details.